# How to parse "rich" path components in Axum?

Tags: url, rust, rust-axum

For URLs paths like:

```
/api/2023-11-01T16-52-00Z/FOO_BAR_BAZ/123_456
```

I would like to use:

```
    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/api/:start/:tokens/:coords", get(stats))
...
async fn stats(
    Path((start, tokens, coords)): Path<(DateTime<Utc>, Vec<String>, (u32, u32))>,
) {
    todo!()
}
```

but I get:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fn(axum::extract::Path<(DateTime<Utc>, Vec<String>, (u32, u32))>) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {stats}: Handler<_, _>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:22:51
    |
22  |         .route("/api/:start/:tokens/:coords", get(stats))
    |                                               --- ^^^^^ the trait `Handler<_, _>` is not implemented for fn item `fn(axum::extract::Path<(DateTime<Utc>, Vec<String>, (u32, u32))>) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {stats}`
    |                                               |
    |                                               required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the trait `Handler<T, ReqBody>` is implemented for `Layered<S, T>`
```

The documentation reads:

> Struct axum::extract::Path source ·
>
> pub struct Path(pub T);
>
> Extractor that will get captures from the URL and parse them using
> serde.

What serde serialisation does it use?  (Serde supports many serialisations.)

How can I get it to parse (URL-safe) ISO timestamps and underscore-delimited lists?

I expect to write parsing functions for these types, but how do I hook them up?

(I could parse all the parameters as `String`s and process them inside the handler function, but I'm hoping that there's a better way.)

Comment: Have you tried `#debug_handler`? It helps track down the cause of these error messages. See https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/attr.debug_handler.html .

Comment: "Using serde" as in the path parameters need to implement `Deserialize` taking a string as a value. You're going to have to wrap your `Vec` and tuple in a type that properly deserializes the strings.

Comment: @Yoric `#debug_handler` stops working code from compiling, with `error[E0107]: trait takes 1 generic argument but 3 generic arguments were supplied`.  It gets confused by a tuple of types.

Comment: @fadedbee Strange, it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several questions, so let's address them one at a time.

## Getting the code to build

The following builds for me

```rust
use axum::{Router, routing::get, extract::Path};
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/api/:start/:tokens/:coords", get(stats));

    axum::Server::bind(&"0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap())
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

async fn stats(
    Path((start, tokens, coords)): Path<(DateTime<Utc>, Vec<String>, (u32, u32))>,
    )
{
    todo!()

}
```

I have only added the `axum::Server::bind(...)`. I suspect that Rust had difficulties inferring your code. In the future, I suggest using `#[axum::debug_handler]`, which improves such error messages.

## Deserialization format

> What serde serialisation does it use? (Serde supports many serialisations.)

Well, data structures compatible with Serde implement `Deserialize`, so let's look at [the definition of `Deserialize` for `DateTime`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#impl-Deserialize%3C%27de%3E-for-DateTime%3CFixedOffset%3E):

> The value to be deserialized must be an rfc3339 string.

also, if you do not like this format, additional formats are provided [here](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/serde/index.html). Ping me if you need help, I'll try and give you a hand.

Now, it's a bit different for our `Vec`. I actually have no clue what the default format is for `Vec`, but I'm willing to be that it's not `_`-separated. So let's implement `_`-separation.

```rust
/// A custom separator to parse `_`-separated lists.
struct UnderscoreSeparator;

impl Separator for UnderscoreSeparator {
    fn separator() -> &'static str {
        "_"
    }
}

/// A wrapper for `Vec`, meant to be deserialized for `_`-separated lists.
#[serde_as]
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct UnderscoreVec(
    #[serde_as(as = "StringWithSeparator::<UnderscoreSeparator, String>")]
    Vec<String>
);

async fn stats(
    Path((start, UnderscoreVec(tokens), coords)): Path<(DateTime<Utc>, UnderscoreVec, (u32, u32))>,
    )
{
    todo!()

}
```

Does this solve your issues?

Comment: Thanks, that looks great.  I'll test it in the morning.

Comment: DateTime<UTC> works, and a few `%3A`s in URLs don't make them too unreadable.

Comment: Vectors working too, thanks.  What (de)serialiser is serdes using here?  Is it JSON, RON, or something else?  (Obviously not one of the binary (de)serialisers.)

Comment: It uses axum's custom deserializer called [PathDeserializer](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/d7258bf009194cf2f242694e673759d1dbf8cfc0/axum/src/extract/path/de.rs#L56).